# Authentication always redirecting to /login

Tags: authentication, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle). 
I created another firewall (see my security.yml below) but when I login and try to access the page localhost/BEL/app_dev.php/back_office I am redirected to localhost/BEL/app_dev.php/login where I logged in. 
The behaviour is exactly the same when I'm not logged in.

I tried to put a $ at the end of my firewall's pattern and the path of my access_control and I could access the page when I was logged in AND when I wasn't logged in (so it wasn't what I was expecting for).

How can I do to access this page only when I am connecting (my user has only ROLE_USER role) ?

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    encoders:
        'FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface': sha512

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main_bo:
            pattern: ^/back_office/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/back_office/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Answer (score 1):

you can always implement an authentication success handler with whom you can intercept the login redirect and do a custom redirect in special cases (eg a backend user logged in)

see [here](http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/10/set-up-authenticationsuccesshandler.html) for a tutorial